# Uploading a 155 GB file to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using `S3Express` on `Windows` to upload a 155GB file on to the S3 bucket using the following command:

```
put E:\<Folder-name>\<File-name>.csv s3://data.<company-name>.org/<Folder-name>/ -mul:100 -t:2
```

But the upload doesn't seem to start at all. It was stuck at the following:

```
Max. Threads: 2
Using MULTIPART UPLOADS (part size:100MB)
S3 Bucket: s3:
S3 Folder: data.<company-name>.org/<Folder-name>/
Selecting Files ...
Press 'Esc' to stop ...
Selected Files to Upload: 1 (154.61GB = 166013845848B) - Use [-showfiles] to list files.
Uploading files to S3...
Press 'Esc' to stop ...
[s=Status] [p=in Progress] [e=Errors] [w=Warnings] [k=sKipped] [d=Dupl] [o=Out]
```

before throwing the following error:

```
Error initializing upload for file : E:\<Folder-name>\<File-name>.csv
E:\<Folder-name>\<File-name>.csv: com_err:7 - Failed to connect to s3 port 443: Timed out - Failed to retrieve list of active multipart uploads
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Done.
Errors (1):
E:\<Folder-name>\<File-name>.csv - com_err:7 - Failed to connect to s3 port 443: Timed out - Failed to retrieve list of active multipart uploads
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Threads: 0 - Transf.: 0B (0B/sec) ET: 0h 25m 30s
Current Bandwidth: 0B/sec (0B left) - Temporary Network Errors: 4
Compl. Files: 0 of 1 (0B of 154.61GB) (0%) - Skip: 0 - Err: 1 (154.61GB)
```

I'm new to `S3Express` and `AWS` in general.

Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `s3://` from the beginning of the destination.  According to the docs, the format is `bucket_name/object_name`.  There is no `s3://` prefix.

These lines should have been a clue to you that something is wrong with your invocation:

```
S3 Bucket: s3:
S3 Folder: data.<company-name>.org/<Folder-name>/
```

Comment: ahh, that was it. Thanks a lot.